# Can't push Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

All of a sudden we can't push our Rails app to Heroku- it's failing the same way on both staging and production environments, as well as a new app we just set up for testing. This app has been running on Heroku for 9 months, with multiple pushes a week, without any issues, but as of yesterday, after some innocuous changes to a model file, we're getting the following error:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
       Bundler Output:  !  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.  !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

---

**UPDATE:**
What's crazy is that we just rolled everything back to the last commit that *had* successfully deployed to Heroku, and it's *still* failing. In other words, the exact same code deployed fine a few days ago, and now we're getting this error.

??

Comment: I think somewhere in your code there is a syntax error. can you run it in development?

Comment: yea it runs fine locally

Comment: do you have `ruby '2.0.0'` at the top of your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed in the Gemfile

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. All of a sudden it doesn't accept push anymore and it gives this useless error: sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @joscas - glad someone can confirm! when did it start for you?

Comment: Just noticed this afternoon. I hadn't pushed since yesterday

Comment: Started last night for us. I'll create a ticket with Heroku now that I'm not alone- will update...

Comment: Was looking at help.heroku but I haven't found anything yet. Please update. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a heroku problem. But just as a test, is it possible to create a new app on heroku and do a test push on that?

Comment: @8bithero- yes we tried that, same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had similar issues with a couple of our Heroku apps. We figured out that a recent Heroku stack upgrade changed how they parse Heroku config variables. One of our variables had a double quote `"` that threw a syntax error when attempting to bundle. I suggest checking your Heroku config variables to make sure there is not open parenthesis or double quotes

you can check this by running `heroku config`

Comment: BINGO that's exactly what it was- got rid of parenthesis and double quotes in our config vars and everything's back to normal. THANKS!

Comment: We deployed a fix for this, you should be able to deploy even with un-matched parens in config now.

Comment: **UPDATE:** As @Schneems said, the Heroku team got back to me and fixed this quickly, so should no longer be an issue. Incidentally the issue was a result of changes they rolled out to make app environments available in all builds, which is a welcome improvement. For details see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/416